# SQL Query, number of city and continent

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with a query.

[image]

I have to find for all the continent: the name of the continent, number of cities and number of countries. This is what I did

```sql
SELECT co.continent, COUNT(*)
FROM Country co 
    JOIN City c ON c.countrycode = co.code
GROUP BY co.continent
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Country co2
WHERE co.continent = co2.continent ( <---- ??? )
GROUP BY co2.continent
```

But I don't know if is it legal the part "WHERE co.continent = co2.continent" because the second query isn't a subquery of the first, is it? Is there another way to do this query?

Comment: There are a couple of issues in that query, one - the output from both UNIONED queries has to have the same number of columns selected AND the type of the respective columns must be the same first with first etc. But that WHERE clause you mention does not look like it is required. You dont have to have a WHERE and the GROUP BY also seems redundant

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, I forgot that rule, thank you.
But if I use a distinct keyword for both quary, and Ill add co2.continent output in the second quary (and by removing where and group by) may fix it? or is wrong in general having that UNION?
Because, if I am not wrong, the first quary returns the number of cities, the problem now is how to find also the number of country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UNION` is not required, a single query with `GROUP BY` and `COUNT` aggregate will get the desired result, there could be multiple cities in the same country, a country could appear multiple times, use `COUNT(DISTINCT...)` to remove duplicates.

```
SELECT co.continent, COUNT(*) cities, COUNT(DISTINCT co.code) countries
FROM Country co 
JOIN City c ON c.countrycode = co.code
GROUP BY co.continent
```

`co.continent = co2.continent` in the original union query is invalid. Queries in union are independent from each other.

Comment: I didn't know I can use distinct inside a aggregate function, thank you!